# Export Two tables in SQL server to Single Excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, console-application

I am new to C#... I am creating an application two tables in SQL server to a single Excel sheet. I export one table to excel successfully but I have no idea export 2nd table the same Excel sheet and the Two table are differently placed in the excel cells...so can't join the tables below my code  Help me to solve this

```
class ExportToExcel
    {

        private Excel.Application app;
        private Excel.Workbook workbook;
        private Excel.Worksheet previousWorksheet;
        private static string CONNECTION_STR = "Integrated Security=True";

        public ExportToExcel()
        {
            this.app = null;
            this.workbook = null;
            this.previousWorksheet = null;
            createDoc();
        }

        private void createDoc()

        {
            try
            {
                app = new Excel.Application();

                app.Visible = false;
                workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        public void shutDown()

        {
            try
            {
                workbook = null;

                app.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)

            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());
            }

            finally
            {
            }
        }

        public void ExportTable(string query, string sheetName)

        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STR);
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;

            try
            {

                Excel.Worksheet oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                oSheet.Name = sheetName;
                previousWorksheet = oSheet;
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                int columnCount = myReader.FieldCount;
                int rowCounter = 3;
                while (myReader.Read())

                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < columnCount; n++)

                    {

                        addData(oSheet, rowCounter, n + 1, myReader[myReader.GetName(n)].ToString());

                    }
                    rowCounter++;
                }


            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                if (myReader != null && !myReader.IsClosed)

                {
                    myReader.Close();
                }

                if (myConnection != null)

                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                }

                myReader = null;
                myConnection = null;
            }

        }


        public void createHeaders(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int row, int col, string htext)

        {
            worksheet.Cells[row, col] = htext;


        }

        public void addData(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int row, int col, string data)

        {
            worksheet.Cells[row, col] = data;

        }


        public void SaveWorkbook()
        {

            String folderPath = "C:\\My Files\\";

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {

                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

            }
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            string fileNameBase = today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            String fileName = today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            string ext = ".xlsx";
            int counter = 1;

            while (System.IO.File.Exists(folderPath + fileName + ext))
            {

                fileName = fileNameBase + counter;
                counter++;
            }

            fileName = fileName + ext;

            string filePath = folderPath + fileName;

            try
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(filePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            ExportToExcel export = new ExportToExcel();
            export.ExportTable("SELECT * from Table_1", "Data");
            export.SaveWorkbook();
            export.shutDown();
        }





    }
```

Comment: You can't export to one worksheet two tables.  You would need to join the two tables before exporting.

Comment: I can't Join Tables because of two tables are placed different places on the same sheet

Comment: Cant you use  SSIS  to export table data in same excel sheet and call this package using C#

Comment: You need to save the position of the last column that you inserted data into from the first table. Then you would add 1 to the saved position and insert the table 2 headers there and then insert below the table 2 headers.